# How do I represent a multi-block cylindrical system in XDMF v2?

Tags: hdf5, hdf

I can represent my HDF5 [files using XDMF](https://www.xdmf.org/index.php/Xdmf2_Model_and_Format_Archive) (specific type XMF used in CFD). But it is recognizing my R-Z coordinates and X-Y coordinates. It thinks I am working in 2D Cartesian X-Y. In other words, the variable `X` is actually Radius, `R` and `Y` is actually `Z`. How to correct this?

Here is the relevant snippet of XDMF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Xdmf SYSTEM "Xdmf.dtd" []>
<Xdmf Version="2.0">
<Domain>
   <Grid
    CollectionType="Spatial"
    GridType="Collection"
    Name="Collection">
 "<Time Value="1.691e+02" />

<Grid Name="mesh1" GridType="Uniform">
  <Topology TopologyType="2DSMesh" NumberOfElements="167 167"/>
  <Geometry GeometryType="X_Y">
    <DataItem Dimensions="167 167" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="HDF">
     Test_000000169.h5:/g01/X
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem Dimensions="167 167" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="HDF">
     Test2_000000169.h5:/g01/Y
    </DataItem>
  </Geometry>
  <Attribute Name="p" AttributeType="Scalar" Center="Node">
    <DataItem Dimensions="167 167" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="HDF">
     Test2_000000169.h5:/g01/p
    </DataItem>
```